# Directive is not showing the directions in Angular google maps

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using angular google maps in my angular 4 application. I am trying to get directions from a point to another point using directive.

Here is directive source code,

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GoogleMapsAPIWrapper} from '@agm/core';

declare let google: any;
@Directive({
  selector: '[appDirection]'
})
export class DirectionDirective implements OnInit {

  @Input() org;
  @Input() dst;
  constructor(private gmApi: GoogleMapsAPIWrapper) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(' In directive ');
    this.gmApi.getNativeMap().then(map => {
      const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
      const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsService.route({
              origin: {lat: this.org.latitude, lng: this.org.longitude},
              destination: {lat: this.dst.latitude, lng: this.dst.longitude},
              waypoints: [],
              optimizeWaypoints: true,
              travelMode: 'TRANSIT'
            }, function(response, status) {
                        if (status === 'OK') {
                          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        } else {
                          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
                        }
      });

    });
  }

}
```

And I have added this in app.module.ts under declarations array.
I am using this directive in another component, inside component I am defining org and dst as follows,

```
showDirections( ) {
    const dst = {longitude: this.point.longitude, latitude: this.point.latitude};
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        const org = { latitude: position.coords.latitude, longitude: position.coords.longitude};
        console.log('Src ' + org.latitude );
      });
    }
    console.log('Dst' + dst.latitude );
  }
```

I am calling above function on a user clicking a button.

The HTML for the component is as follows,

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom" appDirection [org]="org" [dst]="dst">
      <agm-marker  [style.height.px]="map.offsetHeight"  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

I am applying directive as an attribute to agm-map.

When I click on the button which sets org and dst, then direction should display on agm-map. But no directions is currently displaying. 
Please correct me, where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Now I am getting the error as follows,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
```

org and dst are undefined in directive, but they are set in component.

Answer (score 0):

I did workaround and finally able to solve the problem,

Here are the changes I have made,

HTML,

```
<agm-map  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
      <appCycleDirection *ngIf="dst !== undefined" [org]="org" [dst]="dst"></appCycleDirection>
      <agm-marker  [style.height.px]="map.offsetHeight"  [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>
```

and for Directive, I changed the selector as,

selector: 'appDirection'